# Run script in automator (without terminal)

Tags: macos, terminal, automator

After trawling through Stack Exchange and other forums for a few hours, I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong!

cliclick automates mouse movements on macOS. When running the following command in terminal it runs/works as it's intended to.

```
cliclick w:750 m:2656,1138 w:750 m:2827,1000
```

However, I would like to create a .app to avoid running/opening the script in terminal.

When pasting my command into the Automator > Run Shell Script and testing the result is:

```
cliclick: command not found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably installed `cliclick` in `/usr/local/bin` which is not part of the search path the *Run Shell Script* action uses. To overcome this just specify the full path within the action

```
/usr/local/bin/cliclick w:750 m:2656,1138 w:750 m:2827,1000
```